# Is the map $(g_\ast \mathcal{O}_Y)_{g(p)} \to \mathcal{O}_{Y,p}$ always injective

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Let $\psi : A \to B$ be a ring homo and let $g : \mbox{Spec} B \to \mbox{Spec} A$ be induced map. Is true that the map $(g_\ast \mathcal{O}_Y)_{g(p)} \to \mathcal{O}_{Y,p}$ is injective?  $Y = \mbox{Spec}(B)$ and $X = \mbox{Spec} A$. $p$ is prime ideal of $Y$.

Comment: Of course not. Try simple examples first!

Answer (score 1):

This is very false.

Consider the canonical ring map $\phi: \mathbb Z  \rightarrow \mathbb Z/(2)$. We have an induced map $\operatorname{Spec} \mathbb Z/(2) \rightarrow \operatorname{Spec} \mathbb Z $. This has $\phi$ as a map of global sections. Now note that $0$ is a prime ideal, and its image under $\phi^{-1}$ is $(2)$. This gives a map $\mathbb Z_{(2)} \rightarrow \mathbb Z/(2)$, which is not injective.

Comment: I'm not sure if this is right ... I'm very tired ...